# How to return the last recorded ID in access db

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ms-access

I need to insert a record in an access database and return the Id for that inserted row
I try to use Execute non query for inserting then execute scalar with statement as :

```
`"SELECT @@IDENTITY`"
```

and it return 0 all the time

```
"SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
```

Throw an exception !

So is their any way for this issue !

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using? What's the exception?

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is a T-SQL/SQL Server only command and not available in MS Access. For MS Access, use `SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM YourTableName`....

Answer (score 2):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() only works in SQL Server, not Access.

You should be able to use `SELECT @@Identity` to get the last ID - so long as there is an identity column. See this Microsoft KB article for an example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815629